# How to open Direct Console User Interface in ESXI server

Tags: vmware, esxi, esxi5.5

I have an ESXI hypervisor installed on a server with centOS installed as a guest operating system and have it's terminal opened. I want to open Direct Console User Interface (that black and yellow configuration menu) as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the black/yellow part just press F2 to configure your system. After giving it an actual network configuration you will be able to use the web interface to do further configuration.

Comment: I need to open that black/yellow page that's the whole problem. I have tried Alt+F2  but DCUI does not open.

Comment: From your picture you're sitting in front of the machine and have a keyboard attached, correct? If neither F2 nor F12 are working check whenever the keyboard is working at all. One option would be to disconnect it (to test it individually) the other would be to reboot the machine and trying to access the BIOS. If that doesn't work the keyboard is faulty. Also, as the screen states, it's just F2 and not Alt+F2.